# Titan's Ocean and its waves

Tags: terraforming

I've been researching as much as I can about Titan and possible terraforming and what that might look like, however I'm confused on a few things:

1. If we heat Titan up and bring its underground ocean to the surface how deep would that ocean be and would it cover the entire moon (I'm thinking there might be islands but I'm not sure if even Doom Mons would be submerged)? I've also read that the waters would be still (waves maxing out at roughly 1 foot), but is that the case worldwide... or moonwide I should say? With such little gravity I might have thought the waves would have been quite tall or unusual in some way?

Comment: Please try to narrow this down to one question and focus on that. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding we have a strict 1 question per post policy. Can you [edit] this to narrow the focus down to one question?

Comment: It would seem difficult to flood a moon's surface by extracting a subterranean ocean because the void left by removing the water is likely to collapse. In the same way you can't increase the size of a brick tower but extracting bricks from the bottom of the tower and putting them on top.

Comment: You’re closer but count the number of question marks in there. What is the single problem you want solved in this post please. Sea level? Him much heat are you adding?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The surface of Titan is made of water ice. It looks like rock and behaves like it at the local temperatures, but if you warm the planet, you will create a water world with an 875 km deep ocean. As the image shows, that is deep enough to solidify the deepest layers of the ocean through sheer pressure.

Warming Titan is rather pointless due to that, not to mention that if there is a cryogenic biosphere using the liquid ethane and methane as a solvent, it would be ecological genocide.

If you want to live on Titan, excavate caverns and isolate them. Any sort of terraforming project would either result in a hard-to-maintain ocean world or require the stripping of the eater layer. Which is a logistical nightmare for basically zero payoffs. Just build spin-gravity habitats if you are interested in Lebensraum.

Comment: Also, if you crank the surface temperature up by 180 degrees so all the ice melts, the atmosphere is going to massively heat up and expand and a huge amount of it will simply blow off into space. That's probably not going to be good news for surface habitability, even over quite short timescales.